# Keyrock enabling two factor authentication

Tags: authentication, fiware

I am trying register a user in my keyrock installed on my own computer.
I put localhost:8000/ in firefox, and it redirects me to fiwareLab. But when I want to sing up a user, everything is ok, but then, when I guess that I have to confirm the account, the page show me "Activation key invalid" and in my console, the computer show me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqOyV.png)

So, I think that I have to enable the two factor authentication, but I don't know.

Could you help me, please?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Please post the console messages in the question itself

Comment: What do you really want to do? Just create another user? Or something else more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a new user, you have to do the following steps:

In the IdM Horizon login screen, instead of put username, password and click sign in, just click on `Sign up` link or use `idm_ip:8000/sign_up/` directly on your browser. After that, type information about the new user (`username`, `email` and `password`), check the `I accept FIWARE...` box and click `Sign Up` button.

Now, out of the container, see the log through:

```
docker logs <container_name>
```

There, you will see, in the last lines of the log, the activation link that was supposed to be sent to the new user's email. Copy it, paste on your browser and modify the `fiware-lab` host on the url specifying your `IdM Keyrock address`. This way, your new user will be activated through the passed code.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Thank you very much. everything is okay. But one thing, If I want that this link that you say, it (the link) be sent to the user who just registered in Fiware.
Maybe I don't explain well. mmm... I want that this link be sent to the email user who has just registererd.

Comment: In this case you will have to install and configure an email server to treat the delivery of messages...

Comment: Yes, I think, I have smtp installed. But, For example, in the folder local_settings.py of horizon, I can see:
- EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
-EMAIL_PORT = 25
-EMAIL_HOST_USER= 'username'
-EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
And I think that,  in EMAILHOST_USER I have to introduce the email of user who has just registered, but I don't know how can I save this email.

Comment: No. In this case, you have to provide the credentials from the sender account. This is the e-mail that Will send all the activation codes for all new users. Did you get it?

Comment: mmm I don't undersstand very well. I know that I have to send the activation  link to the new user. But I need to know the new user email, but I don't know how. 
I think that in the last comment, I show you several field like EMAIL_HOST_USER and other more, and I think that there I have to put the new user email. is it okay?
If not, I don't understand how can I send the activation link to the new user.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: The sender account will be my personal account.

Comment: As explained in the last comment, you have to put your credentials, since you will use your personal account. This setup is related to the e-mail used to send all the messages from the server.

Comment: Yes, I understood. I have put my credentials in this fields (EMAIL_HOST, ...) but look, this is my file local_settings.py

.....
#EMAIL_BACKEND ='django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'


DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'no-reply@gmail.com'   
EMAIL_URL = 'http://localhost:8000' 
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = '[FIWARE Lab]' 
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com' \n

EMAIL_PORT = 587

EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'manuel@gmail.com'

EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'hola'                            
........

is It  not correct? Because it doesn't work

Comment: You have to search how to use gmail service to send emails, knowing exactly what information is used in each parameter of the settings. In the last section of the following link, you can find an example of email configuration: http://fiware-idm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup.html